# setting a default variable for user input in python

Tags: java, python

I've been thinking this over a day now, I just want to make a default variable for user input so that I will not get a NameError.

```
def function1():
    global user
    user = input("Enter here: ")
def function2():
    if user == "Hello":
        print("Invalid"):
    else:
        print("Granted")
function2()
```

I already tried the, user = input("Enter here: ") or "Hello" but I still get an error message NameError: name 'user' is not defined. I just want to get the else statement.

p.s. I'm sorry for my English, I wish you understand what I want to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obligatory - don't use globals. They get messy and rearchitecting a solution to avoid them generally results in much better results.

With that out of the way, lets use some globals!

First, it seems you've misunderstood what the global keyword does. It allows you to write to a variable that is defined outside of the functions scope. The variable needs to already exist outside of your functions scope. You can **read** globals without this, which is why `function2` in your examples will be fine without it.

Which means your example code should work as intended if you add the following to the start of your file;

```
user = None
```

By calling `function2` first, your user would have have been asked for this input, so the default (`None` in my example) will be in the user variable. But if you call `function1` then the user will be asked, the variable updated, which means calling `function2` after that point will have what the user wrote.

Note: You might have your if statement back to front. At the moment "Hello" is an invalid username, but everything else would be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In `function2`, the variable `user` is undefined.

If you want to refer to the global one as you did in `function1`, you have to add the line `global user` in `function2` as well.

And I suppose you have already called `function1` before calling `function2`.

Comment: That's true, though `global user` is only really needed if he wants to write the value of the global variable. If he just wants to read it, that is not necessary. However, if `user` is a global variable, he should define it in the global scope. A global variable should not be defined in a function scope. Still, global variables are not recommended. Probably a return value is enough for the example provided

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable before you call the 2 functions and you're calling `function2()` before calling `function1()` so the variable doesn't have any value yet.

After you declare the variable before you call the 2 functions you need to use `global user` in `function2()` too, or just put it all in the same function